# What is history and concept of code annotation?

Tags: c#, annotations

C# and Java has code attribute and code annotation. I don't know about other languages, but I know the code annotation feature is used to expand language itself.

I knew what it is, but I want to know how it developed over time. I want to know its history. How it demanded and how it implemented. Is this possible to implement this in kind of concept on LISP, Smalltalk or C++?

And is there a general term to call the concept of annotation?

Comment: The term you are looking for is [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), I think.

Comment: I have read somewhere that **annotations biggest discovery(or improvement) in java in the last 10 years**. **XML** was simply over used for anything and everything, with the entry of annotations its usage might go down.

Comment: Metaprogramming and annotations are really rather opposites: metaprogramming lets do things (mostly arbitrary computations) at compile time that are normally associated with execution time. Annotations let you do things normally associated with compiling (e.g., affecting code generation) at run time instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I don't think it's that simple. For example Reflection.Emit certainly is metaprogramming, but it lets you do things (define types and methods) and runtime that are usually done at compile time.

Comment: @svick: What definition make it "certainly" metaprogramming?

Comment: @JerryCoffin, the widely accepted one, I think: “[Metaprogramming is the writing of computer programs that write or manipulate other programs …](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)”. What definition do you use?

Comment: @svick: At least I see it normally used, metaprogramming involves manipulating the program itself at the source code level. Something like a parser generator or compiler wouldn't normally qualify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually is related to reflection, since reflection is the only way to look at attributes or annotations (depending on the language). So it might be possible for LISP but not for C++.

Also, annotations are only a series of name/values that are tagged to a specific class, method, field, etc.

So inside the meta-object that stores information about a class (ex. it's methods, fields, etc.), one needs to add another map (or list) that contains information about all the attributes an class or method contains.

Obviously, if you don't know what a meta-object is, you should study meta-programming a little, particularly CLOS (Common Lisp Object System), that is the mother of all languages implementing metaprogramming.

Comment: Annotation are not all runtime. Java have source-only annotation. They can be traced back to pre-processors.

Comment: Agreed and there are some post-compilation tools that use Attributes in C# to modify the compiled code (PostSharp is an example).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak much for Java Annotations but C# Attributes were introduced in the first version of .NET when Microsoft was pushing Web Services heavily. Attributes allow you to provide metadata about your code (or metaprogramming as it were) that the framework can look at and use to enhance your code. For instance in .NET 1, you could use the WebMethod attribute to tell the framework that you want to expose a method over a Web Service. The framework would handle the rest.

In C++ people use Preprocessor Directives and Macros to perform Metaprogramming. Other languages (like Lisp and Boo) have Metaprogramming built into the language. [This article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) provides a great starting point on the topic.